# String Concatenation with Comma and Single Quotes E.g. ('ABC','DEF','GHI,'JKL')

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching on internet how to Concatenate/Join Single quotes and comma on the String in vb.net's RichTextBox control. Example ('ABC','DEF','GHI,'JKL') I found this code online today it works even there's leading and trailing spaces and even lines are removed but the (' and ') are missing. Can you guys modify the code?

```
Code:
RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text.Trim, "\s+", "','")

Inside the RichTextBox1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL

Result: ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL

Desired Result: ('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL')
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, anyway, you may to *join* strings instead of *concat* them.

Comment: Something like `Dim t = "(" & String.Join(",", RichTextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(a) $"'{a}'")) & ")"`. Adjust to suit if you really want the new lines in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, there are multiple ways this could be done. Here's another:

```vb
myRichTextBox.Text = $"('{String.Join("'," & ControlsChars.Lf & "'", myRichTextBox.Lines)}')"
```

Note that I have used `ControlChars.Lf` where I would usually use `Environment.NewLine` because the `RichTextBox` always uses that line break. I assume that it has something to do with the RTF format and compatibility.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, I'm getting error with "ControlsChars.Lf"...

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney I tried  these codes RichTextBox1.Text = $"('{String.Join("'," & Environment.NewLine & "'", RichTextBox1.Lines)}')" it worked.

Comment: @ThirdyLeon, I haven't checked but, if `ControlChars` is not available, that suggests that you're targeting .NET Core (which includes .NET 5.0) rather than .NET Framework. Some VB-specific types and features aren't available and `ControlChars` may be one of those. The only issue with using `Environment.NewLine` is that, if you manually type into the control and hot `Enter` then you'll get a lone line feed and you'll then have mixed line breaks. Not the end of the world but not ideal. Are you actually using RTF at all? If not, why not just use a `TextBox` rather than a `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
    ' starting RichTextBox1 contains
    '       ABC
    '       DEF
    '       GHI
    '       JKL

    Dim lns() As String = RichTextBox1.Lines
    For x As Integer = 0 To lns.Length - 1
        lns(x) = String.Format("'{0}',", lns(x))
    Next

    lns(0) = "(" & lns(0)
    lns(lns.Length - 1) = lns(lns.Length - 1).TrimEnd(","c)
    lns(lns.Length - 1) &= ")"
    RichTextBox1.Lines = lns
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how many lines you are dealing with in a real scenario, I chose to use a `StringBuilder`. It creates mutable (changeable) strings saving us throwing away and recreating strings many times.

Start off the `sb` with the initial `"("`. Then the loop uses an interpolated string with an embedded variable for each `line`. `AppendLine` will add a new line after the text.

Lastly we display the new string. In .net we can string the dot notation working left to right. First convert the `StringBuilder` back to an actual `String` with `.ToString`. Next we clean up the end of the new string by removing the final comma and the final new line. A new line is actually composed of 2 Chars, carriage return and line feed. Lastly I added the final ")"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines() = File.ReadAllLines("some text file path")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.Append("(")
    For Each line In lines
        sb.AppendLine($"'{line}',")
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString.Trim({","c, Convert.ToChar(13), Convert.ToChar(10)}) & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Mary, I'm not using text file. The data is copied from notepad and pasted to RichTextBox1. Tried your codes also, it didn't work.

Comment: So sorry, I have edited my code. I inadvertently added a space after each comma.